# Problem with deque: map<..., deque<> > fails, but vector and list aren't?

Tags: c++, stl, deque

I have a code:

```
typedef map<Coordinate3D, deque<someClass > > someMap;
someMap *newEM;
someMap::iterator iter;
//...
(*newEM)[iter->first].insert((*newEM)[iter->first].end(),
                             iter->second.begin(), iter->second.end());
```

that intended to merge two `someMap`. But there is a problem that crashes program due to memory errors(`0xcdcdcdcd` pointer). And that is happening only if map contains deques, and everything works fine when there are lists or vectors. What might it be?

Here is memory problem when I'm using deques. Insert calls a bunch of copy-constructors.
Also I have some property of `someClass` that after copying points to memory that looks like this:

> 0x00959B48  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Right before error occures(in copy-constructor of `someClass`), this field(of copying object) points here(same address):

> 0x00959B48  f0 9b 95 00 00 00 00 00

There is something that looks like address not far away from here(`0x00959B48`):

> 0x00959B0F  fd ab ab ab ab ab ab ab

Other pointers to that one copying object also point on invalid memory(`0xcdcdcdcd` <- thanks MSVS in debug mode for pointing that out).

Then I set memory write breakpoint for that address(`0x00959B48`) and thats what I found:

```
 msvcr100d.dll!memset...//breakpoint activated here
 msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock...
 msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg...
 msvcr100d.dll!operator delete...
 program.exe!someClass::~someClass()  Line 294 + 0x21 bytes C++
 program.exe!std::swap...
 program.exe!std::iter_swap...
 program.exe!std::_Reverse...
 program.exe!std::reverse...
 program.exe!std::deque<...>::_Insert...
 program.exe!std::deque<...>::insert...
```

So what we have is destruction of that object.

```
 msvcr100d.dll!memset...
 msvcr100d.dll!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl...
 msvcr100d.dll!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl...
 msvcr100d.dll!_nh_malloc_dbg...
 msvcr100d.dll!operator new...
 program.exe!std::_Allocate<std::_Container_proxy>...
 program.exe!std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>::allocate...
 program.exe!std::_Deque_val...
 program.exe!std::deque<..>::deque<..> >()
 program.exe!std::map<...::operator[]
```

and so on value several times changes inside STL code like this:

```
if (_Right._Myproxy != 0)//<--breaks here
        _Right._Myproxy->_Mycont = (_Container_base12 *)&_Right;
```

into this

> 0x00959B48  08 f6 12 00 00 00 00 00

and finally back to what we have at the end

> 0x00959B48  f0 9b 95 00 00 00 00 00

So what we have is object being destroyed, memory overwritten, and object goes back to the same memory filled with garbage(which is probably map data).
I substituted deque with list and vector and both worked fine.
So there is a question: what the hell happened with deque, or maybe I'm doing this wrong way and how should I resolve this?

**Edit**: Here is function code:

```
void MergeEffectsMaps(EffectsMap **dest, EffectsMap *src) {
    EffectsMap *newEM = *dest;
    EffectsMap::iterator findIter;
    for (EffectsMap::iterator iter = src->begin();
            iter != src->end(); iter++) {
        findIter = newEM->find(iter->first);
        if (findIter != newEM->end()) {//exists
            if (!iter->second.empty())
                findIter->second.insert(findIter->second.end(),
                    iter->second.begin(), iter->second.end());
        } else {
            if (!iter->second.empty()){
                (*newEM)[iter->first];
                (*newEM)[iter->first].insert((*newEM)[iter->first].end(),
                    iter->second.begin(), iter->second.end());//<----problem
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is someClass:

```
class someClass {
public:
    complexClass1 *value1;
    complexClass2 *value2;
    float value3;
    int value4;
    someClass(){
     value1=new complexClass1 ();
     value2=new complexClass2 ();
     value3=0;
     value4=0;
    };
    someClass(const FieldEffect& cp_val){
     value1=new complexClass1 (*cp_val.value1);//copy-constructor
     value2=new complexClass2 (*cp_val.value2);
     value3=cp_val.value3;
     value4=cp_val.value4;
    };
    ~someClass(){
     delete value1;
     delete value2;
    };
};
```

Comment: How is the original code merging 2 maps when you only have 1 iterator?

Comment: `someMap *newEM;` You've `new`'ed this, right?

Comment: Yes, of course there is 2nd iterator.

Comment: newEM I initialized as pointer to existing map that passed to the function using **. here is the code http://pastebin.com/3BVWPPVT

Comment: Youtch, what's up with all those pointers? C++ has *references*, those are quite useful for such situations...

Comment: The first step to debug your problem would be rewrite the function with references (rather than pointers), and with proper names for the elemnts. Consider using `ElementMap::key_type& src_key = iter->first;` and then referring to it with `src_key`... those type of changes will not *solve* anything, but they will let you see the forest behind the trees (i.e. the algorithm).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for this. I just used to C code and pointers make more sense to me. I'm working on native understanding references.

Comment: Could you provide the complete definition of the class someClass (copy-ctor, etc) and a compilable example of code that reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a copy constructor in `someClass` but no assignment operator.

As soon as something "interesting" happens to the objects, you will leak the old values and then have two objects pointing to the same `complexClass`. When the first of those deletes its pointer, all the copies will have invalid pointers!

Trying to copy one of these invalid objects will break the way you have seen.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Something made me believe I should only define only copy-constructor: `The container may
copy elements using a copy constructor or an assignment;` <-- sais Stroustrup(3 ed.) about vector, and nothing said about deque.

Comment: @Grumm -- See [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are invalidating the iterators with `insert`. For most containers, you have to re-set the iterator value after each insertion, i.e.:

```
it = container.insert (it, element);
```

instead of just:

```
container.insert (it, element);  // it may not be valid anymore
```

Comment: I looked again, and there is nothing to be invalidated(edited post), there is only one iterator may be affected - `iter`, but I'm using it only to read data from `src` map, the other iterator `finIter` used once only to detect whether such key value exists in other map.